# SCSS mixins says invalid CSS error

Tags: sass

I have the following SCSS file containing mixins.

```
@mixin respond-to($media) {
    @if $media == screen-xs {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $screen-xs-min) {
            @content;
        }
        @at-root .no-mediaqueries #{&}{ @content };
    } @else if $media == screen-sm {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
            @content;
        }
        @at-root .no-mediaqueries #{&}{ @content }
    } @else if $media == screen-md {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $screen-md-min){
            @content;
        }
        @at-root .no-mediaqueries #{&}{ @content }
    } @else if $media == screen-lg {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg-min){
            @content;
        }
        @at-root .no-mediaqueries #{&}{ @content }
    }
}
```

When I try to access the webpage, it shows the error:

> Invalid CSS after "...mediaqueries #{": expected expression (e.g. 1px,
>   bold), was "&}{ @content };"

Any ideas? I updated the sass gem to 3.2.13 but I don't know if the compass-rails gem was also updated.

Comment: Shouldn't `$media == screen-xs` be like this: `$media == "screen-xs"`?

Comment: None of those changes affected the problem.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that copying styles like inside and outside of the media queries is going to lead to a very bloated CSS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@at-root` directive requires Sass 3.3, which is still in development.  You'll need to upgrade Sass using the `--pre` flag:  `gem install sass --pre`.

Comment: Even after updating the sass gem, I still get the same error. Is it because the compass gem still uses sass 3.1?

Comment: Check your version (`sass --version`)?  I'm running Sass 3.3.0.rc.2 (Maptastic Maple), and your code compiles fine for me.

Comment: @user1742188 Yes it is due to Compass being on a lower version than 1.0.0 (sass 3.3 is only supported in Compass versions greater than v1)